# div background scale to fit in iOS Devices

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fit an image in the div (Bootstrap theme used), it works fine in the desktop version, but in mobile device specially iOS (Safari) its not scaling to fit properly.

This is what I've tried :

```
      .full {
                background: url('../../../Content/images/16029.jpg') no-repeat center;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;                                
            }
```

For ref : https://tta.allsoft.co

Comment: was the answer below not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

background cover: Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges - w3schools 
if you would like it to all if in the window you would not want to use cover but a percentage or viewport width and height but I warn you that it will distort the image.

```
background-size: 100%;
```

or

```
background-size: 100% 95%;
```

or

```
background-size: 100vw 100vh;
```

if you use two numbers the first one controls the width and the second number controls the height.  For more on this visit [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)